# Find the power series solution to $xy'' - y'-4(x^3)y = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What I am having trouble with this question is making all the n's equal in order to group the summations into one.

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: You need to show your work so people can assist you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $x=0$ is a singular point. Let $y=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}a_nx^{n+k}$. Substituting into the ODE, you have
$$\begin{align*}0&=\sum_{n\ge0}a_n(n+k)(n+k-1)x^{n+k-1}-\sum_{n\ge0}a_n(n+k)x^{n+k-1}-4\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^{n+k+3}\end{align*}$$
I'm assuming your precise problem is the re-indexing of the series to match up the powers of $x$? The first two series are already matching - notice that their leading terms (when $n=0$) has degree $k-1$, while the leading term of the last series has degree $k+3$.

To rectify this, replace $n$ with $n-4$. This means $n+k+3$ changes to $(n-4)+k+3=n+k-1$, and the series now starts at $n=4$.
$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^{n+k+3}=\sum_{n-4\ge0}a_{n-4}x^{(n-4)+k+3}=\sum_{n\ge4}a_{n-4}x^{n+k-1}$$
But now the third series starts at $n=4$, while the other two remain at $n=0$. Overcoming this is a matter of removing the first four terms ($n=0,\ldots,3$) from each of the other two series.
$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_n(n+k)(n+k-1)x^{n+k-1}=\sum_{n\ge4}a_n(n+k)(n+k-1)x^{n+k-1}+a_3(k+3)(k+2)x^{k+2}+\cdots+a_0k(k-1)x^{k-1}$$
$$\sum_{n\ge0}a_n(n+k)x^{n+k-1}=\sum_{n\ge4}a_n(n+k)x^{n+k-1}+a_3(k+3)x^{k+2}+\cdots+a_0kx^{k-1}$$
Now you can group the series together to end up with
$$0=(\text{indicial polynomial})+\sum_{n\ge4}\bigg(a_n(n+k)(n+k-2)-4a_{n-4}\bigg)x^{n+k-1}$$

Comment: So does is there a "right" way about we do this part? I mean instead of bringing the last one down by four and keeping the first two the same as you have shown, instead bring the first two up by one, and the last one down by three and make everything to x^n? When do you know to make something x^n , x^n-1, or whatever? And how do you know to start at n=0, n=1, or whatever?

Comment: @Mike this is not the only way to do it. I merely chose this way to minimize the index-shifting among all three series.